# Need help creating a calculator, can't import sympy

Tags: python, numpy, calculator, sympy

```
import math
import numpy as np


print('Choose 1: Solve For Quadratic equations\n')
print('Choose 2: Solve For Linear Equations\n')
print('Choose 3: Find The Sandard Form\n')
choice = int(input('Choose between 1 2 and 3:'))
for i in range(0,3):


if (choice == 1):
  print('\nSolve the quadratic equation: ax**2 + bx + c = 0')
  a = float(input('Please enter a : '))
  b = float(input('Please enter b : '))
  c = float(input('Please enter c : '))
  delta = (b**2) - (4*a*c)
  solution1 = (-b-math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
  solution2 = (-b+math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
  print('The solutions are {0} and {1}'.format(solution1,solution2))
  break

elif (choice == 2):
  from sympy import *
  x, y = symbols(['x', 'y'])
  system = [
    Eq(3*x + 4*y, 7),
    Eq(5*x + 6*y, 8)
 ]
   soln = solve(system, [x, y])
   print(soln)
```

i dont understand why i get this error everytime:
ImportError: No module named sympy on line 25 in main.py. You can find a list of available modules at docs/python.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line on your program

`from sympy import *`

that's trying to get the sympy module.

You can get it by running this from your command-line.

```
 $~ pip3 install sympy
```

Comment: It doesnt't work this is the error i get: "SyntaxError: bad input on line 3 in main.py". I put the pip instal,ler fo sympy after import numpy as np